# Dynamically load specific User Control from postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a menu on a .aspx page, which will load a specific user control depending on which menu option is clicked.  This part is working fine.

The problem I'm running into is when I instantiate a post back from the dynamically loaded user control, the .aspx page is reloaded.  Now after researching a few of the other questions on here, I gathered that I have to recreate the User Control each time the post back is instantiated.  However, the question I have might be quite simple, but how do I reload the specific User Control (and fire an event such as OnClick) based on what is posted back to the server?

So my question is:  What exactly gets passed back to the server on post back, and is there something in the post back request that will allow me to load the specific control?  If there is, how would I get to it?

Comment: are you using `if(!IsPostBack)`

Comment: What are you using as your menu ? Am I right, that you are trying to figure out which option was selected ?

Comment: Kasun: No, I'm not using if(!IsPostBack)

Comment: KrisW: I'm using the asp:Menu control.  I'm trying to figure out how to return to the specific user control that initiated the post back.  This control is initially loaded from the menu, but I don't think I'm specifically trying to figure out which option was selected.

Answer (score 1):

To do it the manual way, you would have to recreate the control(s) before ViewState is reloaded, like during `OnInit` for example.

There is a control called the `DynamicControlsPlaceHolder` that takes care of persisting dynamic controls for you. It's a definite time saver, and it makes persisting dynamic content easy.

Here is a link to the control:
http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx

To better understand what postbacks do, you need to understand the ASP.NET page lifecycle. Here is an MSDN article that explains it in detail:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: That's the question though.  What exactly does postback do so I may be able to 'capture' the appropriate user control, and call it on page_init?